# MBP with Separate Bluetooth Module

Tags: bluetooth

I have a MacBook Pro 13.3" - Mid 2017 (A1708). I've been told by my local Mac repairer that this model has a separate bluetooth module (from the main wifi board) & that it's near impossible to fix or replace & would be 'horrendously expensive' to do so. This essentially means the value of my MBP has dropped considerably (I was in the process of selling it to upgrade). I know you can use a bluetooth dongle but that doesn't help or improve the sell price. Very disappointed as it's my first Mac. Not sure that I want to buy another Mac now.

Comment: What are you asking for/about?

Comment: Really to see if anyone else has had the same issue with this model.

Comment: It might help to be more specific about the issues  BT seems to have on your MBP.

Comment: The BT is not working at all & the icon is not even showing up in the systems preferences. I have taken it to 2 different Mac repairers & both have told me the same thing, that the BT module is separate from the wifi. They both opened the laptop up & showed me where the BT module is located & it is separate. Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something wrong with your Bluetooth module since you think it would have an impact on the resell price? - I would suggest taking it to one or two alternative repair shops to get their take on what it would cost to fix.

As far as I know, the A1708 models use the same IC for both WiFi and Bluetooth, and they use the same part for the WiFi and Bluetooth antenna (combined with the vents). It's not a separate module.

I just did a quick search for a complete logic board replacement spare part for the A1708 - I'm not sure it's your exact model, but this was priced at $225. This includes the WiFi and Bluetooth IC.

Comment: Yes, the BT is not working at all & the icon is not even showing up in the systems preferences. I have taken it to 2 different Mac repairers & both have told me the same thing, that the BT module is separate from the wifi. They both opened the laptop up & showed me where the BT module is located & it is separate. Not sure what to do next.